# Waiting on multiple semaphores without busy-waiting (C/C++ Linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, ipc, semaphore

If I have more than one semaphore, how can I have a process block until at least one of the semaphores is free? I know I can do this with a busy-wait loop such as:

```
// blocks until one of the semaphores in sems is free, returns
// index of semaphore that was available
int multiple_sem_wait(sem_t **sems, int num_sems) {
   while (true) {
      for (int i = 0; i < num_sems; ++i) {
         if (sem_trywait(sems[i]) == 0) {
            return i;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But is there a way to do this without a busy-loop? Perhaps there's some IPC technique other than semaphores that I should be using?

Thanks

Comment: Rather than using semaphores, how about using condition variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here (developers.sun.com, via the Internet Archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20080704011208/http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/waitfor_api.pdf) is a short paper from Sun about how they implemented their `WaitForMultipleObjects` emulation in Solaris. The basic idea is to associate a list of condition variables to a handle (protected by a mutex), and signal all of the condition variables whenever the handle is signaled. Each time you call the emulated `WaitForMultipleObjects`, a new condition variable is created and added to the list of all handles you are interested in. In the `WaitForMultipleObjects` emulation, you block on the condition variable, and check each of your handles when you wake up.

The reason why there is a list of condition variables (and not a single one) is that you may have two threads blocking on handles: thread 1 is blocked on A and B, and thread 2 is blocked on A and C. Signaling B should not wake up thread 2. Since each call to `WaitForMultipleObjects` create a new condition variable, in this scenario, B and C will have one distinct condition variable each, and A will have both condition variables.

For more detailed info, you will need to read the article itself.

Comment: Sun site has dropped the linked URL.  The Internet Archive has a copy: [https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/waitfor_api.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/waitfor_api.pdf)

Comment: The proposed solution here allows to wait for all or for any (selected based on function parameter) "Events" of type `solaris_win32_event_t`. It is an (somewhat old fashioned?) example of how to implement subscription model, but does not provide an answer to the question. So this "solution" would require to solve the problem first before you can use it - by waiting for each semaphore in a separate thread, and signaling the "Event" from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple separate waiter threads, as in:

- Each thread waits on a separate semaphore.
- Upon successfully waiting on the semaphore, any given waiter thread signals (via another semaphore, condition variable, or whatever primitive is most convenient) the thread that wants to "wait on multiple semaphores".

Comment: It seems like this "solution" requires you to solve the problem before you can use it.  So now the waiting thread needs to wait on multiple "whatever primitive is most convenient" to all become signaled instead of multiple semaphores.  Doesn't seem any easier.

Comment: No, it waits on a single primitive which any of the separate waiter threads would signal. As in thread A waits on sem A, thread B waits on sem B, and thread C waits on sem C, but on success any of them post to sem X that the main waiter is waiting on. Of course in reality you'll want to make it a little fancier so the main waiter knows which one(s) succeeded.

Comment: Oh, I got confused by vhallac's mention of `WaitForMultipleObjects`, which can wait for ALL.  Waiting for any is easy, just use `select` or `poll`.

Comment: `select` and `poll` cannot wait for semaphores themselves. You could use pipes to all of the helper threads, along with select/poll, as the shared synchronization object I mentioned, but they're somewhere between 10 and 1000 times slower than a semaphore for this purpose...