# Is there way to wait for multiple synchronization objects in Delphi for mobile platforms?

Tags: android, delphi, synchronization

Delphi has `THandleObject.WaitForMultiple` function, but it is available at Windows platform only. How to wait for multiple synchronization objects (in my case i need to wait for semaphore&event) for mobile platforms?
Is it possible?
I can use kind of workaround if will wait them in cycle with timeout, but it doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Comment: I think this is a limitation of the underlying platform. Windows has quite rich synchronisation primitives in comparison to POSIX platforms.

Comment: Here's [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7780749/8041231) you might be interested in.

Comment: @Victoria Thank you for sharing the link. Seems there is no simple solution. Will try to check what kind of emulation is possible.

Comment: I don't know anything about Java class importing in FMX (fan of native coding), but maybe if you describe the use of waiting in your app. and it's possible to import classes, you may get a proper answer (if you're waiting for all objects, or one from many). For example [CyclicBarrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) can do waiting for all threads reaching it. For one from many I could try to do a deeper search (because I'm not Android developer).